# Image Attribute height: 100% does not work

Tags: html, css

I have a table of 9 cells, all distributed just like a tic-tac-toe board. I want to display an image in one of those cells(top left corner), so I wrote the following **CODE** -

```css
td {
   border: 2px solid black;
   width: 33%;
   height: 33%;
   padding: 0px;
}

td img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: auto">
   <tr>
      <td id="box0"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/010/323/original/00D7-500x500.png?1275328364" alt=""></td>
      <td id="box1"></td>
      <td id="box2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="box3"></td>
      <td id="box4"></td>
      <td id="box5"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="box6"></td>
      <td id="box7"></td>
      <td id="box8"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In the style tag, I made the td height 33%. I want it to take up only 1/3rd of the entire height of the table. Now, inside the td tag, I put an image and set its height to be 100%. I want it to cover the complete table cell without changing the size of the table cell. Therefore, it's height should be equal to 100% of its parent's height. But if I set the image height to 100%, it just covers the complete column of its parent cell, and the other two cells below the image's parent cell are reduced to lines.

In short, the image covers the whole column even when it's height is set to be 100%. Only when I set its height to auto, does it confine itself to its parent table cell. But height: auto should mean that the height of the image is the default, and height: 100% should mean that the image should be confined to its parent cell? Why is the opposite happening?

Comment: I got the X to sort of work by adding 'position: relative' the parent (td) style,  Then I added 'position: absolute;' to the image's style, and increased the magnification to 300% (height: 300%; width: 300%), but then you're going to need to adjust the top and left so that the image is positioned in the right square.  Lastly, make each square's background transparent and the image's z-index -1.  This will prevent the square's border from disapearing.

Comment: @HowardBrown I think you might be misunderstanding my question( or maybe I am misunderstanding you). I want the image in only one of the 9 squares. Is that what you are providing the answer for?

Comment: dont use the <img>. just use the image as a background for needed cell. and playing with different ```background-*``` properties will help you to position and stratch an image as you want.

Comment: This seems to be Chrome/Edge specific behaviour, Firefox (Dev. Ed.) does not show the behaviour and properly displays the square image inside the cell. Simply remove the `height` property completely and use only `width: 100%` and it will work fine in all three browsers.